# Acrobat Pro 2020 fails to install on an m1 MacBook

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, adobe

While running the .pkg file to install Acrobat, a generic prompt is raised after I enter the serial# indicating that installation has failed. When I run Acrobat, it prompts me to enter the serial again, and that immediately raises the following dialog:

[image: Acrobat Error]

I don't have reason to think that the installer is damaged. The package file has been used successfully through Munki (on earlier MacOS versions) for a long time and I've tried copying it and running it manually with the same result.

I googled the error but the most common [solution](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/creative-cloud/kb/configuration-error.html#mac_os) from Adobe is to change the permissions on `Library/Application Support/Adobe/SLStore`, but it doesn't exist. Adding the folder and then granting the permissions also fails.

The Macbook is updated and running MacOS 12.3.1

- Does error 16 apply to missing access to some other system resource for storing the serial #?
- Could there be a missing system integrity protection dialog requesting access to something?
- Could this be a Rosetta2 issue?
- Is Adobe *cursed*?

Comment: [Learn how to fix configuration errors (Error 1, Error 15, or Error 16), which can occur when you launch a Creative Cloud app.](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/configuration-error.html)

Comment: @user16145658 That is the link posted in my question! That solution does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that @benwiggy's suggestion about Python 2.7 being removed from Monterey caused the problem. It turns out that my vendor provided me an outdated installer, while the latest [one](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/download-install/kb/acrobat-2020-downloads.html) installs correctly.

Comment: Also my question about using the most up-to-date installer....!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that Adobe uses python scripts in its installers, and Apple removed the system python from Monterey 12.3.

But realistically, this is a question for Adobe support. Any reason you're not using Acrobat 2022?

Comment: I don't have much faith that Adobe will provide a helpful response, but I am trying. Having the answer to this question might be helpful for the community.
Python was a good idea, installing 2.7 fix the problem either sadly.

Comment: @DanatheSane Installing python won't work if their scripts point directly to the system python (which a lot of scripts do/did).

Comment: So it turns out the installer provided by my organization's licensing people is outdated, the newest one works fine. Thanks.